# Sum result of SELECT...WHERE in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, and if I can get the expect result...
(Keep in mind this is a `VIEW`)

```
SELECT
      [Id]
    , [Nome]
    , [Estado]
    , (SELECT COUNT(EstProc) FROM LoginsImp AS LI WHERE (EstProc = 'A1.' OR EstProc = 'A2.') AND LI.LogImpFiles_Id = LIF.Id) AS ItemsProcessamento
    , (SELECT COUNT(EstProc) FROM LoginsImp AS LI WHERE EstProc = 'A3.' AND LI.LogImpFiles_Id = LIF.Id) AS ItemsErroProcessamento
    , (SELECT COUNT(EstProc) FROM LoginsImp AS LI WHERE (EstProc= 'A4' OR EstProc= 'A5') AND LI.LogImpFiles_Id= LIF.Id) AS ItemSucessoProcessamento
    , SUM(ItemsErroProcessamento + ItemSucessoProcessamento) AS [ItemsProcessados]
    , [CreatedOn]
    , [CreatedBy]
FROM
    [dbo].[LogImpFiles] AS LIF
GROUP BY 
    [Id], Nome, Estado, CreatedOn, CreatedBy
```

The result is this:

```
1   TesteImport1        6   2   3   0   2015-08-04 15:41:41.5130000 110032797
```

I was expecting something like this:

```
1   TesteImport1        6   2   3   **5**   2015-08-04 15:41:41.5130000 110032797
```

Comment: Without seeing your data, how would we know...?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753186/how-to-sum-count-value-in-sql-server

Comment: You have the same name in the alias and in the table too? The sum is not going to use the column alias but the column from the table.

Comment: Handle NULL values using ISNULL when doing SUM.

Comment: @JamesZ Yes,, i will check if that is the problem.

Comment: As for the rest of the comments, i should have explained, the SUM is the result of columns 5 and 6 (so, 2 + 3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JOIN` for your conditional aggregation instead of subquery. And as JamesZ pointed out, the `SUM` is not going to use the column alias.

```
SELECT
    [Id]
    , [Nome]
    , [Estado]
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN LI.EstProc = 'A1.' OR LI.EstProc = 'A2.' THEN LI.EstProc END) AS ItemsProcessamento
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN LI.EstProc = 'A3.' THEN LI.EstProc END) AS ItemsErroProcessamento
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN LI.EstProc= 'A4' OR LI.EstProc= 'A5' THEN LI.EstProc END) AS ItemSucessoProcessamento
    , SUM(CASE WHEN LI.EstProc IN('A1.', 'A2.', 'A4', 'A5') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [ItemsProcessados]
    , [CreatedOn]
    , [CreatedBy]
FROM [dbo].[LogImpFiles] AS LIF
LEFT JOIN LoginsImp LI
    ON .LogImpFiles_Id = LIF.Id
GROUP BY [Id], Nome, Estado, CreatedOn, CreatedBy
```

Answer (score 1):

I am tempted to say "it is just your data".  That is, your question doesn't have enough information.

However, I suspect the problem is `NULL` values.  The `+` returns `NULL` if either value is `NULL`.  So, try this:

```
SUM(COALESCE(ItemsErroProcessamento, 0) + COALESCE(ItemSucessoProcessamento, 0)
   ) AS [ItemsProcessados]
```

Comment: I should have explained, the SUM is the result of columns 5 and 6 (so, 2 + 3), meaning, no NULL's ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    [Id]
    , [Nome]
    , [Estado]
    , ItemsProcessamento
    , ItemsErroProcessamento
    , ItemSucessoProcessamento
    , SUM(ItemsErroProcessamento + ItemSucessoProcessamento) AS [ItemsProcessados]
    , [CreatedOn]
    , [CreatedBy]
FROM
(
SELECT
      [Id]
    , [Nome]
    , [Estado]
    , (SELECT COUNT(EstProc) FROM LoginsImp AS LI WHERE (EstProc = 'A1.' OR EstProc = 'A2.') AND LI.LogImpFiles_Id = LIF.Id) AS ItemsProcessamento
    , (SELECT COUNT(EstProc) FROM LoginsImp AS LI WHERE EstProc = 'A3.' AND LI.LogImpFiles_Id = LIF.Id) AS ItemsErroProcessamento
    , (SELECT COUNT(EstProc) FROM LoginsImp AS LI WHERE (EstProc= 'A4' OR EstProc= 'A5') AND LI.LogImpFiles_Id= LIF.Id) AS ItemSucessoProcessamento
    , SUM(ItemsErroProcessamento + ItemSucessoProcessamento) AS [ItemsProcessados]
    , [CreatedOn]
    , [CreatedBy]
FROM
    [dbo].[LogImpFiles] AS LIF
GROUP BY 
    [Id], Nome, Estado, CreatedOn, CreatedBy
)BASE
GROUP BY 
    [Id], Nome, Estado, , ItemsProcessamento, ItemsErroProcessamento, ItemSucessoProcessamento,CreatedOn, CreatedBy
```